# Combining Parallel loop with thread logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have written a code which looks like this:

```
var allParams = new List<string>(); // supposingly has 10 items inside it
var secondCollection = new List<string>(); // collection of 100
Parallel.For(0, secondCollection.Count(), new ParallelOptions { 
MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, counter => 
{
    callingSomeMethod(params[counter]);
});
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way here how to combine my params collection with the parallel for loop to make somethnig like following:

- when 10 threads start at the same time, I'd like to pass all 10 elements inside the callingSomeMethod method, and when one of these threads end, then I'd like to just simply start allover again passing element at position 0 , 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3...

And so the cycle would repeat itself until the Parallel.For loop would end it's cycle...

Is this doable with Paralllel loops? I'm not really sure how would I implement this, can someone help me out ?

Comment: Have you tried it?  What errors/issues did you encounter?

Comment: @Kyle No I'm actually not even sure how to start it, it's still "blurry" in my head, which is why I started the discussion to see if it's doable

Comment: Just try it.  It'll probably work.  Btw, I think you meant `counter % allParams.Length`.  Passing `counter` as is will cause you to get `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception.

Comment: `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` does not guarantee that 10 threads will be used. Only that 10 is the maximum.

Comment: @PeterBons it doesn't really matters how many threads would be used at a time, just that when 1 thread gets released, next available string from allParams is used

Comment: @Kyle do you mean allParams.Count? It says it doesn't have this parameter

Comment: There are no guarantees as to how many threads `Parallel` will use.

Comment: It's not clear what goes to `callingSomeMethod` - contents of second or first collection?

Answer (score 0):

So you have sort of a "jagged array," two lists of different lengths that need to be zipped together for processing, with the shorter of the two lists repeating as needed.  That about it?

How about something like this?

```
var allParams = new List<string>(); // supposingly has 10 items inside it
var secondCollection = new List<string>(); // collection of 100
var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(secondCollection); //Copy of 100

while (queue.Count > 0)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(allParams, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, 
    (param) =>
    {
        string item;
        bool ok = queue.TryDequeue(out item);
        if (ok)
        {
            callingSomeMethod(param, item);
        }
    });
}
```

The idea is that you put items from the longer list in a [ConcurrentQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287208(v=vs.110).aspx), then iterate over the shorter list repeatedly until the queue is empty.  Each iteration gets an item from the iterator in `foreach` loop and from the queue, and can process both items together.